# Google MAPS waypoints

Tags: maps

I have a problem using waypoints in Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults

I want to add waypoints and get driving directions in the order I provide them, but google automatically optimize them...

I send request with this code:

```
var request = {
  origin: start,
  destination: end,
  waypoints: waypts,
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

and in my array (waypts) waypoints are ordered as they should be ...

Example:

I want to go from NY via Chicago via NY to Philadelphia.. But the response I get is like this: NY via NY (1 meter) to Chicago to Philadelphia. Google somehow optimize route but I don't want this ...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

LOL ... I missed that in documentation... The solution is:

In var request put the line:

```
optimizeWaypoints: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply removing this line:

```
optimizeWaypoints: true
```